# Dynamically change the width of JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jdialog

I have created a JDialog which contains a JLabel. Because the length of text, which changes based on users' input, can contain a large number of characters, there is the need to dynamically change the length of the JDialog based on the size of length of the JDialog. I have tried the pack() method but it's not the case for it. Can anyone give me some tips? Thanks in advance!

Comment: pack() will work! If it doesn't work then you need to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `getPreferredSize` for `JLabel` - basically you have to get `textLength` from `JLabel` in pixels, there are 3 correct ways, but I love:

   ```
   SwingUtilities.computeStringWidth(FontMetrics fm, String str)
   ```
2. Now you are able to `setPreferredSize` for `JLabel` correctly (please by defalut is there needed to add +5 - +10 to the `Integer` that returns `SwingUtilities.computeStringWidth`)
3. Call `pack();` on the top level container (the `JDialog`).

Comment: -1 there is no need to go to all this trouble. By invoking label.setText(...) the component is automatically revalidated and repainted. The preferred size is automatically recalculated. All that is necessary is the pack() after the setText().

Comment: @camickr thanks for comment, agreed in case if there is some LayoutManager used, not AbsoluteLayout();, then you can set dynamically nothing();

Comment: a JLabel always has a preferred size whether you are using a layout manager or not.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Try invoking [`validate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate%28%29) on the `JDialog`.</strike> I just realized that this will not work.

---

Here's a nice [thread](http://www.javakb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/java-gui/1249/JFrame-does-not-automatically-resizes-to-JLabel-s-length) that discusses this issue. I would recommend listening to the answer and suggestions provided by @Andrew Thompson, who's actually a prominent user here.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to put the text into a `JTextArea` and put that in a `JScrollPane`.

#### E.G.

[image: Text Area in Scroll Pane]

#### Code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ExpandingText {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final String s = 
                    "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  ";

                final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(s,5,30);
                textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                textArea.setLineWrap(true);
                textArea.setEditable(false);
                textArea.setFocusable(false);

                JButton button = new JButton("Add Text");
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                            textArea.append(s);
                        }
                    });

                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));
                panel.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                panel.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, Makes more sense to me as well. I doubt the users like seeing the dialig continually changing is size just because the text of one field changes.

Answer (score 2):

Why will `pack()` not work for you?

You could use [setSize](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setSize%28int,%20int%29) and base the width off the width of the `JLabel`.  Call this method whenever the user changes the input.

Comment: It is rarely a good idea to use setSize(). You need to know the size of all the other components on the dialog as well when determining the overall size. Let pack() do the job. T

Comment: I will update my answer to reflect the usage I thought about.

Answer (score 1):

Trying using the `validate()` method, this will cause the `JDialog` to lay out its subcomponents again

**EDIT**

This apparently will not work

Comment: I didn't downvote but validate() will not change the "width of the Dialog" which is what the question is asking. The pack() method is used for this.

Comment: Ahh I see I thought it would. My mistake. Blind downvotes dont let anyone know what is going on.

Comment: @Hunter, +1 to negate down-vote. I suggested the same thing, but realized it was not true.