# stop horizontal scrolling in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, jscrollbar

I want to add a `JTextArea` to an application. Normally that textarea contains large content and both horizontal and vertical `ScrollBars` appear when running that application. I want to remove horizontal scrolling; I have found that it is possible with 
`HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER` field but then it does not show the complete contents (it doesn't wrapped horizontally and move content to next row). how to overcome this. I want to stop horizontal scrolling and put contents in next row without scrolling it on a row.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845382/dynamically-change-the-width-of-jdialog/6845744#6845744) for an example.

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
yourJTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
yourJTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

Comment: You don't need to set the horizontal scroll policy, just the wrapping policy.

Comment: Remove explicit horizontal scroll policy change; it is unnecessary.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, works fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the scroll bar policy:

```
JScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

This will disable the horizontal scroll bar

Comment: -1, Why would anyone upvote this answer? The question clearly states the poster has tried using "HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER" and it doesn't do what the poster wants.

Comment: There was nothing about HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER in the original post, if the OP edits his post without comment, that isnt my fault.

Comment: Click on the link to the right of the "edited" label and you will see the original text.

Comment: My mistake, I swore there wasnt anything there.

Comment: so sorry I think it was a my mistake because i was not highlighted 'HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER' filed in my original post. I said it but didn't highlighted. sorry for that and thanks for answering.

Comment: @Mad, it is not your fault. The highlighting is nice but not necessary. We need to take the time to fully read the question. What is important is that you accept an answer once you get a solution.